# Combine two mutually exclusive byte arrays into one

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-shift, bit

I have 2 byte arrays of 5 bytes each. Each byte array represents 40 flags and I need to combine both arrays into one array of 5 bytes. Each of the byte arrays are mutually exclusive which helps, Although I would prefer to validate they are mutually exclusive.

So my question is, how can I combine the two mutually exclusive byte arrays into one.

The only way I can think of doing it is bit shifting across both arrays and comparing each value, but there must be an easier way of doing it. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "mutually exclusive" here, or what your inputs and expected outputs are. A [mcve] would *really* help to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I assume that a bit set in one should never be set in the other. Though probably best wait for confirmation from OP. :)

Comment: @Chris: Indeed. Although that would suggest just using `|`, without any shifting. Basically, the question is too unclear to answer at the moment...

Comment: `|` to combine, `a&b==0` to validate exclusiveness

Comment: @JonSkeet By Mutually exclusive I mean that if 1 bit is set in one array it can't be set in the other. You say that I would be able to use `|` do you mean that I would be able to do `b1[0] | b2[0]`. Didn't even think it would be that easy, I thought you would still have to look at the bits? For my own knowledge in the future would you be able to tell me what you initially assumed I meant by mutually exclusive? Ive never heard it being used with any other meaning than I used it.

Comment: @Keithin8a: You used the term "mutually exclusive" with respect to the *bytes* - you didn't even mention bits until the end of the question. Two bytes being mutually exclusive makes no sense - whereas two bytes having a mutually exclusive set of "on" bits makes a lot more sense. And yes, `|` (with a cast) sounds like it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Looking at byte level, an array `{ 1 }` and the other array `{ 3 }` would be mutually exclusive (`1 != 3`), but on bit level (`{00000001}` and `{00000011}`), the same values would not be mutually exclusive because of the least significant bit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh I thought of that, that's why I specified that each array was 5 bytes long and represented 40 flags. I could have probably made it more clear than that, but thanks for the help clearing it up.

Comment: It's just quirky terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine bits in one byte with bits in another byte, you can use the bitwise-or operator `|`. This operator will set a bit in the resulting byte if that bit was set in first or second byte.

Example:

```
byte b1 = 0x12; // 0001 0010
byte b2 = 0x81; // 1000 0001
byte result = (byte)(b1 | b2); // Results in 0x93 = 1001 0011
```

To combine the two arrays:

```
byte[] flags1 = ...;
byte[] flags2 = ...;
byte[] result = new byte[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    result[i] = (byte)(flags[i] | flags[2]);
```

Using the bitwise-AND operator `&` you can find out if any bit is set in both bytes. Example:

```
byte b1 = 0x93; // 1001 0011
byte b2 = 0x1A; // 0001 1010
byte result = (byte)(b1 & b2); // Results in 0x12 = 0001 0010
```

To check if bits are NOT set in both arrays:

```
byte[] flags1 = ...;
byte[] flags2 = ...;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    if ((byte)(flags[i] & flags[2]) != 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Flags cannot be set in both arrays.");
```

Comment: You'll need to cast - the result of `flags[i] | flags[2]` is an `int`, not a `byte`. (And I think you mean `flags1[i] | flags2[i]`.)